# can i check a Bitcoin payment is valid before I pay for exchanges? can I check the receipt number and the transfer number somewhere or with anyone?

Tags: transactions, validation

i am due to receive a Bitcoin payment  i earned i would like to chat or speak by phone with a broker or a management account specialist and references the receipt number and the transfer number provided to me to make sure the exchange is satisfied with both parties before i pay for the transfer fees

Comment: It sounds like you might be getting scammed and the "transfer fees" is just a trick to get money from you. What company is this and how did you earn bitcoin with them?

Comment: Hi ejessejamz, I voted to close as a duplicate since I had the same thought as Vojtěch immediately. If we got that wrong, please edit your question with more information so that we can reopen your topic.